# Spring boot: Different Multipart configuration for different api in same application

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible to have different multipart configuration for different endpoints in **same service**.
For ex. 
**v1/upload/uploadDoc1** - 
max-file-size=1MB and max-request-size=5MB

**v1/upload/uploadDoc2** - 
max-file-size=5MB and max-request-size=20MB